# Can't restore state from code created ViewController

Tags: swift, state-restoration

I'm trying to restore ViewController created from code. I'm trying to make very simple example but I don't understand why it doesn't work. An application changes background color of view by clicking on image and should save it when app is stopped. I'm trying to store and restore Bool property, and basing on it app changes views background color. When I'm testing it I'm sending app to background by cmd + shift + h, after that stop app from xcode and open it again, but it doesn't save selected background color.

1. I've enabled restoration option in AppDelegate
2. In ViewController I've set restorationIdentifier and restorationClass
3. Adopted protocol UIViewControllerRestoration in extension to ViewController and implemented encoding and decoding methods
4. Implemented ViewController restoring method

AppDelegate class

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

ViewController class

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sunny: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            setColor()
        }
    }

    lazy var colorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var changeColor: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Change", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(change), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.restorationIdentifier = "myVC"
        self.restorationClass = ViewController.self
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupUI()
    }

    @objc func change() {
        sunny.toggle()
    }

    func setColor() {
        colorView.backgroundColor = sunny == true ? .yellow : .darkGray
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerRestoration {

    func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(colorView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            colorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            colorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            colorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width),
            colorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
        ])

        view.addSubview(changeColor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            changeColor.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            changeColor.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorView.centerXAnchor),
            changeColor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            changeColor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45)
        ])

    }

    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(sunny, forKey: "isSunny")
        super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }

    override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let isSunny = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "isSunny") as? Bool else {return}
        sunny = isSunny
        setColor()
        super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }

    static func viewController(withRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [String], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = ViewController()
        return vc
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you aren't using User Defaults? Just from the example you've provided this would be my first choice to store the background color of the app.

Comment: I've watched ReyWenderlich example and in that example this stuff which i use is enough for restoring. Of course I know that we can save it to UserDefaults, but we can even not use UIViewControllerRestoration protocol to achieve this.